# AVPlayerViewController の controlStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c

これまで動画再生には MPMoviePlayerController を使用していたのですが、iOS 9.0 からdeprecated となったので AVPlayerViewController に乗り換えようと思っているのですが、MPMoviePlayerControllerで、

moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

とした時に画面左上に表示されていた再生を終了する[Done]ボタンをAVPlayerViewControllerで表示させる方法がわかりません。

avPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

としても再生コントロールは表示するのですが、再生を終了するボタンがありません。
AVPlayerViewController を使って再生画面を表示する時に[Done]ボタンもしくは再生終了させるボタンを表示させる方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presentViewControllerメソッドで、AVPlayerViewControllerをモーダル表示すれば、「Done」ボタンが表示されます。（iOS 9.1のシミュレータで確認しました）

モーダル表示ではなく、UINavigationController内で表示しているという場合には、アプリ側で「Done」ボタンを作る必要があると思います。